# eclipse indigo install zend debugger failed?

Tags: eclipse, zend-debugger

ubuntu 10.4 + eclipse indigo
first install pdt pulgin success, but it not include zend debugger
then install new software
add repository: PDT - http://downloads.zend.com/pdt

error info is followlings:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger,5.3.18.v20110322
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger.linux.x86,5.3.18.v20110322
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.zend.php.debug_feature,5.3.18.v20110322

how to do?